# How to connect Android on RabbitMQ?

Tags: android, rabbitmq, amqp

I'd like to use RabbitMQ client from an android App. 
From the server side, i use SpringBoot with spring AMQP. RabbitMQ (rabbitmq_server-3.4.3) is installed correctly and an integration test valid the server behaviour.

The difficult part is when i try to create a connection from RabbitMQ connectionFactory inside my android project.

I get this exception :

```
failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1 (port 5672): 
connect failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
```

In android manifest, Internet permission is set :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

Here is my code :

```
public class LoadingTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Integer> {

    private static String replyQueue = "REPLY_QUEUE";

    public interface LoadingTaskListener {
        void onResourceLoaded();
    }

    private final ProgressBar progressBar;
    private final LoadingTaskListener loadingTaskListener;
    private ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;

    public LoadingTask(ProgressBar progressBar, LoadingTaskListener loadingTaskListener) {
        this.progressBar = progressBar;
        this.loadingTaskListener = loadingTaskListener;
        this.connectionFactory = new ConnectionFactory();
        connectionFactory.setAutomaticRecoveryEnabled(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {

            /*init rabbitMQ Context*/
            Connection connection = connectionFactory.newConnection();
            Channel channel = connection.createChannel();
            channel.basicQos(1);
            channel.queueDeclare(DATA_QUEUE.getName(), false, false, false, null);
            AMQP.Queue.DeclareOk q = channel.queueDeclare();
            channel.queueBind(q.getQueue(), "amq.fanout", "chat");
            QueueingConsumer consumer = new QueueingConsumer(channel);
            channel.basicConsume(replyQueue, true, consumer);


            /* initiate RPC */
            String corrId = java.util.UUID.randomUUID().toString();

            AMQP.BasicProperties props = new AMQP.BasicProperties.Builder()
                .correlationId(corrId)
                .replyTo(replyQueue)
                .build();

            AmqpRequest request = new AmqpRequest(LIST_IMAGE);
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            String jsonRequest = gson.toJson(request);

            channel.basicPublish(MAIN_EXCHANGE.getName(), DATA_QUEUE.getRoutingKey(), props, jsonRequest.getBytes());

            String response;

            while (true) {
                QueueingConsumer.Delivery delivery = consumer.nextDelivery();
                if (delivery.getProperties().getCorrelationId().equals(corrId)) {
                    response = new String(delivery.getBody());
                    break;
                }
            }

            System.out.println(response);

        } catch (IOException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // Dummy Data until i can't connect to rabbitMQ
        return 1234;
    }
}
```

Is it really possible to connect Android on RabbitMQ, or should i use a kind of http bridge ?
Could anyone provide me an exemple for both http bridge or RabbitMQ connection.

Thank you

Comment: Are you sure port(5672) is open on the destination machine?

Comment: Also, bear in mind that `localhost` on an Android device or emulator is the Android device or emulator, not your development machine.

Comment: You're right, i just forget that localhost on my emulator isn't the localhost of my development machine.

Comment: how do we connect to the local machine (without using dyndns), i have tried using the LAN address of my dev machine but its not working so far..